# Flat button changes color on mouse press

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

3D buttons aren't a problem.  It's the flat buttons (when `Button.FlatStyle == FlatStyle.Flat`).

I set the background color of the button `Color.Black`.  When I press and hold the left mouse button, the background color changes to a gray color, which I am trying to prevent.

I've tried some Mouse events triggered by the button, especially MouseDown.  I've also used the BackColorChanged event and still didn't work.

In short, when the mouse is down, the button is grey.  When the mouse is up, the button is black.  How do I prevent that?  How do I keep the button black?

Comment: Have you inspected the `FlatAppearance` (expandable) property?

Comment: Oh, found something.  Guess I'm answering my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing property `Button.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor` works like a charm:

```
private void FocusBtn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    FocusBtn.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Black;
}
```